# Flutter go_router How to handle unknown route?

Tags: flutter, dart, routes, navigation, flutter-go-router

How can I handle the unknown routes navigation in the app with `go_router ^6.5.0` in Flutter, so when GoRouter doesn't have the route needed to be navigated it opens `UnknownRoutePage(originalLocation)`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `errorBuilder` of `GoRouter` while setting up the `_router`

```
final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
  routes: [...],
  errorBuilder: (context, state) => const ErrorScreen(), // Your desired screen
);
```

---

Example:

`ErrorScreen`

```
class ErrorScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const ErrorScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
        title: const Text("Error Screen"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => context.go("/"),
          child: const Text("Go to home page"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`Route`:

```
final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      name: "home",
      path: "/",
      builder: (context, state) => const HomePage(),
      redirect: (context, state) {
        if (userIsNotLoggedIn){
          return "/login"
        }
        return "/"
      },
    ),
  ],
  errorBuilder: (context, state) => const ErrorScreen(),
);
```

Comment: It's okay but when you are in the ErrorScreen, it's not possible to go back, also IOS back gesture is not working. Even context.pop not working as it can't find the previous route. It's not even possible to context.push or context.go to the needed route. How to fix this?